# Reference author year website in LNCS

Tags: lncs

How do I write a website reference in author year format in [LNCS style](http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) is the preferred way here to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: and please care to add a proper reference (eg. link) to everything which is not *built-in* TeX or CTAN package